# I want to delete all checked lists pressing the delete button but I don't know how

Tags: javascript, checked

I'm learning Javascript and now I'm making to-do list.I've finished the basic one but I want to add the delete button which delete all the checked lists to my to-do list.
I've tried some ways that I came up with and they all failed and I cannot find the answer by googling.

How can I do this ? If there is someone who know, please teach me . I'd appreciated if you could show me how.

this is my code ↓　the error happened saying cannot read property 'parentElement' of null at Object.deleteAll

```
deleteAll: function() {
    let taskListItem, checkBox, checkBoxParent;

    for (i=0; i<this.taskListChildren.length; i++){
      taskListItem = this.taskListChildren[i];
      checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector('input[type = "checkbox"]:checked');

    
      checkBoxParent = checkBox.parentElement;

      checkBoxParent.remove();

    }

document.getElementById('deleteChecked').addEventListener('click', () => {
    tasker.deleteAll();
  });
```

// this is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onLoad = "tasker.construct();">
  <div class="tasker" id="tasker">
    <div class="error" id="error">Please enter a task</div>

    <div class="tasker-header" id="tasker-header">
      <input type="text" id="input-task" placeholder ="Enter a task">
      <button id="add-task-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="tasker-body">
      <ul id="tasks">
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button id="deleteChecked">Delete</button>
  </div>
  
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like checkBox is null. Can you put a console.log() to taskListItem and check what it is?

Comment: `querySelector` inside of a `for` loop seems a little awkward...why not use `querySelectorAll` to get all the checked inputs at once, and then loop through them?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well because your `deleteAll()` function could be written in several ways depending on the structure of your HTML.

Comment: -Scott Marcus  Okay! I posted

Comment: -David784 I did that but now I have the problem like this

Comment: -David784   cannot read property 'remove' of undifined

Comment: -Martin Cornejo Saavedra  I tried but taskListItem is not defined

Comment: I took https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtgY3a_TPg0 as reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery library and solve it as follows.

Step 1) Define in your html button element:

```
<button id="button" onclick="reset()"> RESET </button>
```

Step 2) define the 'reset ()' function, like this

```
function reset()
{
    $("input:chceckbox").removeAttr("chcecked");
}
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you  for  answring my question !  I'll try this

Comment: Is it for removing the classes ?

Comment: Or for removing the lists from ul?

Comment: @ 西山 功 一 no, this function selects all specific input selectors of the checkbox type and if the attribute "checked" is set for one of them, it removes it, thus canceling the selections at the checkbox.

Comment: @ 西山 功 一
don't forget to import the jQuery library in the header (between the <head> and </head> tags) of your html like this:

`<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>`

Comment: ＠Petr Fořt Fru-Fru　Okay！I didn't import that. I 'll try again. Thank you